# Recovering Deleted Files after Emptying Trash on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I moved a complete folder to the trash, then I emptied my trash.

How do I recover those deleted files which I emptied from the trash on OS X Lion?

By searching with Google, I have found a few tools which do this. Either they cost a fortune or they are lousy. Is there a manual and generic way to recover these files?

Comment: Before you go any further, SHUT THAT COMPUTER DOWN! The more you use it (and the more various background activity happens on it), the greater chance that those files will be overwritten by new files, and if that happens your chance of recovery is gone. Use a different computer to research & download tools, etc. When you find a tool you want to use, boot the computer from something else (CD, DVD, external drive, etc) NOT the disk you are trying to recover from.

Comment: Additionally, there's a good chance that you can't recover that data anymore, or only a professional can do it. And as answer to all "how do I recover data" questions, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is one of your best bets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an Ubuntu live cd and a tool like PhotoRec to recover most of the files. The only problem is that it will recover ALL of the files that it can from a partition based on specific file types.

I recently used this tool on a dying drive with SMART errors, corrupt sectors, and a corrupted MBR and yet it worked like magic.

It might be overkill for your needs given that you only need to recover a folder, but if you really need that data, give it a shot.

See here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/